# Multiplying a column by a row value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

My first table looks like:

```
Date        USD    EUR  Count_ids
2018-06-09  5.00    8   1
2018-06-09  15.00   20  3
2018-06-09  5.00    11  1
2018-06-09  45.00   24  2
```

My second table contains daily currency rates;

```
+----+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+-------+
| Id |          Date           | Convertion | From | To  | Rate  |
+----+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+-------+
|  1 | Wednesday, June 6, 2018 | USD TO EUR | USD  | EUR |  0.88 |
|  2 | Thursday, June 7, 2018  | USD TO EUR | USD  | EUR | 0.89 |
|  3 | Friday, June 8, 2018    | USD TO EUR | USD  | GBP | 1.40 |
|  4 | Saturday, June 9, 2018  | USD TO EUR | USD  | EUR |  0.86 |
----+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+-------+
```

I would like to create a new column converting the EUR column in table1 to USD using the same exchange rate date as the transactions dates.

Comment: What have you created so far? What is the issue you are facing? I do not see a question but a request above

Comment: I wouldn't do this as a "column" unless you have a trigger or something that modifies the table on inserts/updates. Rather, a view or just a regular query that you run with joins would suffice... And this seems rather simple so uh... Not sure what issues you could be having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a join:

```
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  t.eur / rates.rate AS priceindollars  
FROM t
INNER JOIN rates
ON rates.Date = t.Date AND rates.From = 'USD' AND rates.To = 'EUR'
```

assuming there is a date in the rates table matching the date in the 1st table.

Comment: `AND [From] = 'USD' AND [To] = 'EUR'`

Comment: I can only see 'USD TO EUR', but I will include it.

Comment: the third row in the sample data has `'GBP'` in the `[To]` column

Comment: Yes I see that now but it has 'USD TO EUR' in a prior column

Comment: yup, confusing data

Comment: Sorry for the confusing data. but the query is exactly what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with a subselect.   You can probably also do it with a CROSS APPLY.